# Powershell pattern to exclude %

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a pattern to remove % from the text. This could have been easily achieved through ESCAPE or replace but I am restricted to only modify the contents of $pattern .

```
$text = "something is 5% and 10% value"
$pattern = "[^!%]*" // only this can be modified.
([Regex]::Match($text,$pattern)).value
```

Output should be :

something is 5 and 10 value

Comment: You cannot remove anything with a `[Regex]::Match`.

Comment: Try  `([Regex]::Matches($text,"[^%]+")).value -join ''` or do a single replace `$text.replace("%","")`

Comment: @revo this script is embedded one, hence nothing can be modified here. only i have to pass the pattern to the script. hence i can't even use replace. :(

Comment: Then there is no chance.

Comment: If you can't change the script, can you modify the input string before it's passed to the script?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ### Remarks
>
> The Match(String, String) method returns the first substring that matches a regular expression pattern in an input string.

If you can only modify the pattern but not the rest of the code it's not possible to achieve what you want.

You need somthing like

```
$pattern = '[!%]'
[regex]::Replace($text, $pattern, '')
```

or

```
$pattern = '[!%]'
$text -replace $pattern
```